# Calling collection.find() causes an internal server error and times out afterwards

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, express

I've got an ExpressJS backend and added MongoDB to it. Previously with hardcoded data it worked perfectly but now that I've (tried) to add MongoDB to the pipeline, my request for the data times out. I've inserted a record in a collection using the command prompt:

```
> db
stackmailer

> db.sites.find()
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("55ef5c1a7f6857848b7149b7"), 
    "title" : "Stack Overflow", 
    "icon" : "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" 
}
```

MongoDB is hosted at localhost:27017

```
2015-09-08T23:58:51.394+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6836 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=JEROEN-LAPTOP
2015-09-08T23:58:51.422+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2015-09-08T23:58:54.760+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51658 #1 (1 connection now open)
```

I'm reading the data like this:

```
var db = require('mongoskin').db('localhost:27017/stackmailer');
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    db.collection('sites').find().toArray(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
        }
        console.log("found sites!");
        console.log(result);
        res.send(result);
    });
}
```

Which is called from AngularJS like this:

```
StackExchangeService.getSites().then(function(data) {
    $scope.data.sites = data;
});

angular.module('StackMailer.Services', [])
    .factory('StackExchangeService', function($q, $http) {
    var service = {
        getSites: function() {
            return getData('/sites');
        }
    };

    function getData(url)
    {
        var d = $q.defer();
        $http.get(url, ({ timeout: 10000 }))
        .then(function(response, status) {
            console.log("successfully retrieved data");
            d.resolve(response.data);
        }, function(response, status) {
            console.log("couldn't retrieve data " + status);
            d.reject(response);
        });
        return d.promise;
    };

    return service;
});
```

After the specified timeout span, "couldn't retrieve data 0" shows in the console. None of the `console.log` calls inside `router.get()` display output in the console.

This leads me to believe that I am somehow not connecting to MongoDB but as far as I can tell, I've got everything setup for that.

Looking at the ExpressJS output, I notice the following output (for 3 requests):

```
GET / 304 5.335 ms - -
GET /css/stackmailer.css 304 4.784 ms - -
GET /js/stackmailer.js 304 1.250 ms - -
GET /sites 500 479.902 ms - 1424
GET /tags 304 2.303 ms - -
GET /css/stackmailer.css 304 0.937 ms - -
GET / 304 1.028 ms - -
GET /css/stackmailer.css 304 1.231 ms - -
GET /js/stackmailer.js 304 1.608 ms - -
GET /tags 304 1.156 ms - -
GET /sites - - ms - -
GET / 304 2.988 ms - -
GET /css/stackmailer.css 304 4.508 ms - -
GET /js/stackmailer.js 304 2.022 ms - -
GET /tags 304 1.336 ms - -
GET /sites - - ms - -
```

Notice the first request to `/sites` which returns HTTP 500 and afterwards times out. This is reflected in the console log:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Curiously: when I wrap the `db.collection()` call in a try-catch block and try to log the error to the console, it doesn't cause the HTTP 500 anymore but I'm also not shown any output.

Any ideas on what could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are not seeing an error logged here, and it is possibly because of some other configuration present in your app not mentioned here.

However the error you "should" be seeing is this:

> Error: URL must be in the format mongodb://user:pass@host:port/dbname

And that is because your connection string is not in a valid format accepted by the driver. It should instead be this:

```
var db = require('mongoskin').db('mongodb://localhost:27017/stackmailer');
```

Noting that the `mongodb://` part is mandatory, and things like the port number ( which is the default ) are not.

I will also note that you appear to have this loading in your "route" module and presumably everywhere else that you intend to use a database connection. It is strongly advised to not do that, as database connections should be made once per application and the connection "shared" where it is needed to be used.

Comment: Oh wow.. It works with that small addition. I thought I was going crazy. I don't get it though -- I've been looking through tutorials ([one](http://www.hacksparrow.com/mongoskin-tutorial-with-examples.html), [two](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/)) and they never mentioned or showed that in the example. Is this a recent addition? I'll make the db a shared object, thanks. I've got a standard ExpressJS project so I'm not sure why it wouldn't show me that error.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Unit testing. Doing tutorials is fine, but the first code you write on any new addition should be a test independant of other code to see that what you expect actually works. In this case a basic test attempting to connect to the database would have highlighed the problem. Also always look for official documentation and examples/tests in the code repository. Here is the github page for [mongoskin](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin) and all examples show the full connection string, or no string for default.